# Unterschied zwischen „spiegeln“ und „widerspiegeln“

Tags: difference

Ich würde gerne wissen, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen „spiegeln“ und „widerspiegeln“ gibt.

Beide übersetzen ins Englisch auf : *to reflect*

Und Duden auch listet spiegeln als ein Synonym für widerspiegeln.

Sind sie wirklich Synonyme? Und wenn Ja, können wir sie in Sätzen tauschen?
Wenn nicht, was ist der Unterschied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Widerspiegeln* wird für *spiegeln* im übertragenen Sinn verwendet.

> Diese Niederlage spiegelt nicht die Qualität der Mannschaft wider.

Manchmal wird *widerspiegeln* auch verwendet, um auf ein Trugbild hinzuweisen.

> Die tiefstehende Sonne spiegelte sich als Kreuz auf der Kugel des Fernsehturms wider.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Auskunft :)

Answer (score 0):

Man kann auf eine spiegelnde Fläche orthogonal schauen, dann wirft sie das Bild zurück und man kann von widerspiegeln sprechen, oder in einem stumpfen Winkel, dann lenkt sie das Bild um und spiegelt nur oder spiegelt etwas, das nicht in der Richtung des Betrachters liegt.